# What is the purpose of setting public key after setting private?

Tags: c, openssl

I wonder why I have to call `EC_KEY_set_public_key` before calling EC_POINT_point2hex having already called `EC_KEY_set_private_key`? Is it already determined by setting the private key?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/ossl_typ.h>

int main()
{
     EC_KEY *eckey = NULL;
     EC_POINT *pub_key = NULL;
     const EC_GROUP *group = NULL;
     BIGNUM *priv;
     BN_CTX *ctx;



     priv = BN_new();
     ctx = BN_CTX_new();

     BN_hex2bn(&priv, "EDCC6224FEE390A57C76C13A9BECC9502A6F3B1BF6F72B6ED11B83A0F0E3E9FC");
     eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
     group = EC_KEY_get0_group(eckey);
     pub_key = EC_POINT_new(group);

     EC_KEY_set_private_key(eckey, priv);

     if (!EC_POINT_mul(group, pub_key, priv, NULL, NULL, ctx))
       printf("Error at EC_POINT_mul.\n");

     EC_KEY_set_public_key(eckey, pub_key);

     char *cc = EC_POINT_point2hex(group, pub_key, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED, ctx);

     char *c=cc;

     int i;

     for (i=0; i<130; i++)
     {
       printf("%c", *c++);
     }

     printf("\n");

     BN_CTX_free(ctx);

     free(cc);

     BN_free(priv);

     return 0;
}
```

According to `libssl1.1` of the `1.1.1f` version, I happend on the following definition:

```
int EC_KEY_set_private_key(EC_KEY *key, const BIGNUM *priv_key)
{
    if (key->group == NULL || key->group->meth == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (key->group->meth->set_private != NULL
        && key->group->meth->set_private(key, priv_key) == 0)
        return 0;
    if (key->meth->set_private != NULL
        && key->meth->set_private(key, priv_key) == 0)
        return 0;
    BN_clear_free(key->priv_key);
    key->priv_key = BN_dup(priv_key);
    return (key->priv_key == NULL) ? 0 : 1;
}

int EC_KEY_set_public_key(EC_KEY *key, const EC_POINT *pub_key)
{
    if (key->meth->set_public != NULL
        && key->meth->set_public(key, pub_key) == 0)
        return 0;
    EC_POINT_free(key->pub_key);
    key->pub_key = EC_POINT_dup(pub_key, key->group);
    return (key->pub_key == NULL) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

I've tried to dive into `libssl1.1` sources provided by the `apt source` but I didn't get hold of the `key->meth->set_private` / 'key->meth->set_public' since that:

```
void EC_KEY_METHOD_set_init(EC_KEY_METHOD *meth,
                            int (*init)(EC_KEY *key),
                            void (*finish)(EC_KEY *key),
                            int (*copy)(EC_KEY *dest, const EC_KEY *src),
                            int (*set_group)(EC_KEY *key, const EC_GROUP *grp),
                            int (*set_private)(EC_KEY *key,
                                               const BIGNUM *priv_key),
                            int (*set_public)(EC_KEY *key,
                                              const EC_POINT *pub_key))
{
    meth->init = init;
    meth->finish = finish;
    meth->copy = copy;
    meth->set_group = set_group;
    meth->set_private = set_private;
    meth->set_public = set_public;
}
```

and

```
user@host openssl-1.1.1f$ grep -R "EC_KEY_METHOD_set_init"
util/libcrypto.num:EC_KEY_METHOD_set_init                  3777 1_1_0   EXIST::FUNCTION:EC
include/openssl/ec.h:void EC_KEY_METHOD_set_init(EC_KEY_METHOD *meth,
crypto/ec/ec_kmeth.c:void EC_KEY_METHOD_set_init(EC_KEY_METHOD *meth,
user@host openssl-1.1.1f$
```

So ... Why do I have to set `pub_key` to `eckey` before calling `EC_POINT_point2hex` with `pub_key` as a parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EC_KEY_METHOD_set_init is provided to modifie the defaults methods but nit used. By default function pointer set_private and set_pucblic are equal to 0.

```
static const EC_KEY_METHOD openssl_ec_key_method = {
    "OpenSSL EC_KEY method",
    0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,
    ossl_ec_key_gen,
    ossl_ecdh_compute_key,
    ossl_ecdsa_sign,
    ossl_ecdsa_sign_setup,
    ossl_ecdsa_sign_sig,
    ossl_ecdsa_verify,
    ossl_ecdsa_verify_sig
};

static const EC_KEY_METHOD *default_ec_key_meth = &openssl_ec_key_method;
```

The definition of EC_KEY_METHOD is :

```
struct ec_key_method_st {
    const char *name;
    int32_t flags;
    int (*init)(EC_KEY *key);
    void (*finish)(EC_KEY *key);
    int (*copy)(EC_KEY *dest, const EC_KEY *src);
    int (*set_group)(EC_KEY *key, const EC_GROUP *grp);
    int (*set_private)(EC_KEY *key, const BIGNUM *priv_key);
    int (*set_public)(EC_KEY *key, const EC_POINT *pub_key);
    int (*keygen)(EC_KEY *key);
    int (*compute_key)(unsigned char **pout, size_t *poutlen,
                       const EC_POINT *pub_key, const EC_KEY *ecdh);
    int (*sign)(int type, const unsigned char *dgst, int dlen, unsigned char
                *sig, unsigned int *siglen, const BIGNUM *kinv,
                const BIGNUM *r, EC_KEY *eckey);
    int (*sign_setup)(EC_KEY *eckey, BN_CTX *ctx_in, BIGNUM **kinvp,
                      BIGNUM **rp);
    ECDSA_SIG *(*sign_sig)(const unsigned char *dgst, int dgst_len,
                           const BIGNUM *in_kinv, const BIGNUM *in_r,
                           EC_KEY *eckey);

    int (*verify)(int type, const unsigned char *dgst, int dgst_len,
                  const unsigned char *sigbuf, int sig_len, EC_KEY *eckey);
    int (*verify_sig)(const unsigned char *dgst, int dgst_len,
                      const ECDSA_SIG *sig, EC_KEY *eckey);
};
```

So `EC_KEY_set_private_key` will set only priv_key and not pub_key wich must be set by `EC_KEY_set_public_key`. In general, having the private key does not mean having the public key but means that we can calculate it. So it is better that it is saved, so as not to redo a heavy calculation several times.

Finally, EC_POINT_point2hex allows to print a point in hex format. yYou print pub_key but it could have been any point on the curve.

Comment: I figured out that it was wrong that one has to set private and public to `eckey`. Actually it's not. So the question is resolved. But thank you for the comments and ref.